# How to select those distinct rows, in which non of value is non positive

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL. 
Let's take an *example*.
**table_a**

```
number   value
  1        1
  1        1
  1        0
  2        1
  2        1
  3        1
  3        0
```

I want all distinct rows which do not have any value 0 in it, as in the above case expected result is 2.
  As we know MySQL doesn't support minus operator, can somebody help me out with the query.

Edit:
 Answer should be 2 by mistake i changed it to 1(edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT number  
FROM mytable
GROUP BY number 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

`HAVING` clause filters out `number` slices containing at least one `0` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f107db/1)

Or, alternatively:

```
SELECT number  
FROM mytable
GROUP BY number 
HAVING MIN(value) > 0
```

The above query selects `number` groups containing *only* positive, non-zero, values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f107db/2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to using the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT number, value
FROM table_a
GROUP BY number, value
HAVING SUM(value) > 0
```

If you want the number of records where both the `number` and `value` equal 1, then I would try the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_a
WHERE number = 1 AND value = 1
```

Comment: Answer should be 2, can you improve your answer.

Comment: I see three distinct non zero rows in your example data.  Why would the answer be 2?

Comment: because number rows=2 all values are 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
number,
DISTINCT(value)
FROM table_a
WHERE value > 0;
```

Comment: you write above you want distinct value which have not 0 ? am i right

Comment: Answer should be 2, can you improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both column Distinct like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, value FROM table_a
WHERE value <> 0;
```

Comment: Answer should be 2, can you improve your answer.